# Window has no text in service mode

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm working on a batch engine because we have a third party software that is a client software that needs to run in a batch

Im using this code to enumerate the process Id's

```
public IEnumerable<int> EnumerateProcessWindowHandles(int processId)
{
    var handles = new List<IntPtr>();
    try
    {
        foreach (ProcessThread thread in Process.GetProcessById(processId).Threads)
            Win32.EnumThreadWindows(thread.Id,
                                    (hWnd, lParam) =>
                                        {
                                            handles.Add(hWnd);
                                            return true;
                                        }, IntPtr.Zero);

    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
    return handles.Select(h => (int)h);
}
```

And then this code to get the Text for each window

```
public string GetText(int hWnd)
{
    // Allocate correct string length first
    int length = Win32.GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
    var sb = new StringBuilder(length + 1);
    Win32.GetWindowText(hWnd, sb, sb.Capacity);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

The window that I'm looking for is never found when executing the program from the Service, If i launch it from a console program It works. If I try to launch calc.exe from the service I get the Calculator window, so its possible to get windows from a service. Output when listening to calc.exe from my service

> 2013-04-16 13:52:09; Verbose; 23000; 1728; 5592; Batch: Window
>   hwnd: 8454324; Title: Calculator
>
> 2013-04-16 13:52:09; Verbose; 23000; 1728; 5592; Batch: Window
>   hwnd: 393910; Title:
>
> 2013-04-16 13:52:09; Verbose; 23000; 1728; 5592; Batch: Window
>   hwnd: 328806; Title: GDI+ Window
>
> 2013-04-16 13:52:09; Information; 23000; 1728; 5592; Batch:
>   Calculator shown

And output when listening to my real application

> 2013-04-16 14:25:16; Verbose; 23000; 5076; 5140; Batch: Window
>   hwnd: 524976; Title: .NET-BroadcastEventWindow.2.0.0.0.218f99c.0
>
> 2013-04-16 14:25:16; Verbose; 23000; 5076; 5140; Batch: Window
>   hwnd: 524978; Title: GDI+ Window
>
> 2013-04-16 14:25:16; Verbose; 23000; 5076; 5140; Batch: Window
>   hwnd: 590366; Title:
>
> 2013-04-16 14:25:16; Verbose; 23000; 5076; 5140; Batch: Window
>   hwnd: 787088; Title:
>
> 2013-04-16 14:25:16; Verbose; 23000; 5076; 5140; Batch: Window
>   hwnd: 656044; Title:
>
> 2013-04-16 14:25:16; Verbose; 23000; 5076; 5140; Batch: Window
>   hwnd: 721578; Title:
>
> 2013-04-16 14:25:16; Verbose; 23000; 5076; 5140; Batch: Window
>   hwnd: 590926; Title:

As you can see most hwnds are titleless, if I do the same but from console mode I get

> 2013-04-16 14:21:08; Verbose; 23000; 4864; 4120; Console: Window
>   hwnd: 66672; Title: MSCTFIME UI
>
> 2013-04-16 14:21:08; Verbose; 23000; 4864; 4120; Console: Window
>   hwnd: 328694; Title:
>
> 2013-04-16 14:21:08; Verbose; 23000; 4864; 4120; Console: Window
>   hwnd: 328754; Title:
>
> 2013-04-16 14:21:08; Verbose; 23000; 4864; 4120; Console: Window
>   hwnd: 197656; Title:
>
> 2013-04-16 14:21:08; Verbose; 23000; 4864; 4120; Console: Window
>   hwnd: 132122; Title:
>
> 2013-04-16 14:21:08; Verbose; 23000; 4864; 4120; Console: Window
>   hwnd: 132178; Title: .NET-BroadcastEventWindow.2.0.0.0.218f99c.0
>
> 2013-04-16 14:21:08; Verbose; 23000; 4864; 4120; Console: Window
>   hwnd: 132100; Title: MSCTFIME UI
>
> 2013-04-16 14:21:08; Verbose; 23000; 4864; 4120; Console: Window
>   hwnd: 132186; Title: Default IME
>
> 2013-04-16 14:21:08; Verbose; 23000; 4864; 4120; Console: Window
>   hwnd: 132176; Title: GDI+ Window
>
> 2013-04-16 14:21:08; Verbose; 23000; 4864; 4120; Console: Window
>   hwnd: 197654; Title: Default IME
>
> 2013-04-16 14:21:08; Verbose; 23000; 4864; 4120; Console: Window
>   hwnd: 132144; Title:
>
> 2013-04-16 14:21:08; Verbose; 23000; 4864; 4120; Console: Window
>   hwnd: 132142; Title:
>
> 2013-04-16 14:21:08; Verbose; 23000; 4864; 4120; Console: Window
>   hwnd: 132140; Title: Default IME
>
> 2013-04-16 14:21:08; Verbose; 23000; 4864; 4120; Console: Window
>   hwnd: 459078; Title: Task Progress
>
> 2013-04-16 14:21:08; Verbose; 23000; 4864; 4120; Console: Window
>   hwnd: 132078; Title: Default IME

I get more hwnds and more titles, the window that I'm interested in is **Task Progress**

Is this solvable? I'm suing Process.Start to start the process

Comment: Does the account under which the service runs have access to the desktop?

Comment: 'Allow service to interact with desktop' is not checked for the service (You can't check it for accounts other than Local system). But it does find the calc.exe window like this?

Comment: that's my guess - yes (and hence it as a comment rather than an answer).

Comment: But calc.exe window is found using above method, so it seems you can get windows without having that option checked. It does just not work for my real winforms program

Comment: You're observing [Session 0 Isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756986.aspx). The service runs in session 0. If *it* launches another program, that other program also runs in session 0. However, if *you* launch the program, it runs in *your* session, not session 0.

Comment: Thanks for reply, yes I'm aware of that, but calc.exe is also launched in Session 0, and i can get its windows allright, but not for my real program.

Comment: @Anders - yes, but if that program tries to do anything even half clever, it probably trips over one or more of the limitations of Session 0 isolation itself and never creates its windows. It's rare for a "featureful" windows application to survive running inside session 0, unless it was specifically designed to do so (in which case I'd normally expect it to expose a sane API rather than forcing you to poke around with its windows)

Comment: Nothing with this software is sane :P Only process I can see that it spawns is scs.exe The software works in Service mode, its just that my monitor code does not

Comment: And I doubt you'll be able to make it work as a service for the reason @Damien_The_Unbeliever has explained.  Why does it need to be a service?

Comment: If we run the batch as a console program in a user session it will be logged out eventually, the only reliable way to run it is as a service. Its sad that we are dependent on shitty third party software but thats nothing I can change. The program works fine executed from a service, but in all their wisdom they spawn message boxes etc when something goes wrong even when batchmode is turned on (command line option). So for it to be 100% stable i need to monitor the program and react to message boxes etc.

Comment: @Anders - all I can recommend at this point is that it's **not** a technical problem to be solved. If the software is *meant* to be usable in a "batch mode", but isn't, you need to persuade your bosses to apply pressure back on the suppliers - e.g. by whatever legal contracts apply between the businesses. If that's a dead-end, you need to replace the product - or tell your bosses that the cheaper solution (for the next year, at least) is to hire someone to watch over the system and hit "OK" on the message boxes (probably, unfortunately, true)

Comment: I wish it was that simple :/

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are on Vista or above since this issue will not occur on earlier versions.
As @Damien_The_Unbeliever said this is a [session 0 isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756986.aspx) issue.

> Is this solvable? I'm suing Process.Start to start the process

It is generally a bad idea to launch a third-party application ( whose code you do not control ) in session 0 viz.

- You do not know if the app was designed to run under the restrictions of session 0.
- Security issues, since you can do greater damage to a system from this session.

Use [CreateProcessAsUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) taking care to set the lpDesktop member of STARTUPINFO to "Winsta0\\default"
& an environment block obtained via [CreateEnvironmentBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762270%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
For how to call these from C# refer to this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2007/12/20/how-to-call-createprocesswithlogonw-createprocessasuser-in-net.aspx)

You can obtain the User Token via [WTSQueryUserToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383840%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the session id is available to services via [WTSEnumerateSessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or the SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE message.

> As you can see most hwnds are titleless,

The reason you can not retrieve window text is because Windows performs this operation by sending a WM_GETTEXT message (see the Remarks section on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), and of course it can't do so as your engine is on the services desktop.

You can work around this in the service by performing your operations in a separate thread on which you have called [SetThreadDesktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686250%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the user's desktop (with caution, see warning in remarks).